# Weird date format in my questions section

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, date-format

I noticed a little inconsistency in the date format in "My questions" section on all StackExchange sites. I attach a screen shot displaying it. I realise it is a very minor glitch, but let us have it as open bug - otherwise it might be neglected overall.

[image]

Notice that both dates happen in 2013, but the one above does not display the year. I have censored the unrelevant part.

Answer (score 2):

The formatting of the date takes into account how long ago it was.

If it is around 11 months or more from the current date, we include a year, otherwise, we do not.

The dates you are looking at fall on either side of this threshold.

Comment: Well this is kind of weird for me. Especially the 11 month interval. Maybe more intuitive would be to get years in all but current year? For me the two dates I posted seem quite further apart formatted like that, than the actual 17 days.